# What is the process to install Microsoft edge with Wine?

Tags: 20.04, wine, executable, microsoft

I have installed wine through the commands in the website "https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu" and not from sudo apt install.

And after that I ran winecfg and it prompted me to install some components so I did that.

And after that I downloaded microsoftedge exe file for windows 10 and when I try to open it with wine by right clicking it and selecting using wine program loader, nothing is happening.

I even tried to do it from terminal by using the command

> wine MicrosoftEdgeSetup.exe

and the result is:
[image: pic1]

The version of my wine is 6.0.

Comment: Do you need it in Wine, because MS does offer a native Linux version of Edge (if you didn't already know that)?

Comment: @PJSingh Yes, I need it on Wine.

Comment: Would see if Wine even supports edge.  Wine works well for only some microsoft programs, not all.

Answer (score 1):

Every one of those "fixme" statements is a syscall that Wine cannot handle. Each statement represents a stub -- *unwritten* code, not *broken* code.

Your approach simply won't work unless you're on a team with a Wine developer who can write those missing syscalls.

Wine is a great, ambitious project with a lot of amazing people. Please keep in mind that it's a volunteer-led project, not a commercial software product. Wine has never promised complete compatibility with all Windows applications. Wine developers do not have access to the Windows source code. Updates to any of the many moving parts (Windows, the application, Wine, or Ubuntu) sometimes improve compatibility...but also sometimes break it.